# jquery regular expression replace digit at second index

Tags: jquery, regex

i have a string as `abcsd[2].asdwdw[3].asdsds`. I need to find and replace digit 3 with other.
i have tried some but they only replace the first or all digits in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var x = 'abcsd[2].asdwdw[3].asdsds';
var newvalue = 5;
var y = x.replace(/(.*?\..*\[)\d+/, '$1' + newvalue)
```